# Mount host system /app as read only inside docker container

Tags: django, docker

How would you mount the host systems /app directory as read only within the docker container?

Use case: developing a Django application running inside a docker container, and you want Django to reload each time changes are made to /app code on the host system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a readonly bind mount is documented under [Use a read-only bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#use-a-read-only-bind-mount).
In your case the command will look something like:

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/app:/app:ro ...
```